Story where a fantasy setting implements an analog Internet
I'm trying to find a short story I read sometime around 2010-2012 about a character in a fantasy setting who devises a long-range communication protocol very similar to the real-world Internet Protocol, using various non-electronic technologies like automated magic spells and carrier pigeons. There was enough similarity to the idea of "IP over Avian Carriers" that it may have been directly inspired by the proposal.
I unfortunately don't remember much about the plot itself, just that (I think) the effort to design and implement the protocol was mostly led by one character. I don't remember whether it was an isekai-style plot where the character was basing the protocol on expertise from our world, or if it was invented wholly within the fantasy world. I think the implementation itself mostly worked as expected and the story dealt more with cultural and social changes that resulted from it.
As for where I read it, it's possible it was featured on either of the podcasts PodCastle or Escape Pod - but I've searched both sites for terms like "protocol" and "pigeon" and didn't find any matches.

There's the Clacks in late Discworld books, inspired by real 19th century semaphore relay networks...

@Shawn which also included the idea of meta information ("overhead"). After Sir Terry Pratchett's  death any number of  technically minded fans started to include the "X-Clacks-Overhead" http request/response headers  with his name, alluding to the (deceased) John Dearheart character from Going Postal who indeed invented the message protocol for the clacks before he was booted out (and eventually killed, after which his name started "traveling in the overhead"). So that might be an answer.

GNU Terry Pratchett

I wonder if it's part of the Wiz series by Rick Cook. A programmer gets pulled into a fantasy universe and uses magic like computer programs.
